# USB drive recognized in logs, but no device file for it

Tags: linux, usb, arch-linux

I'm trying to mount a flash drive ([16 GB Cruzer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001T99ZTI)) on my Arch Linux desktop. It works fine on my Arch Linux laptop, so it's not a problem with the drive.

The drive is in `/var/log/messages.log.3`:

```
Dec 16 20:20:45 localhost kernel: [5876090.739078] usb 2-2: new high speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
```

It's in `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0781:5530 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer
```

But it's not showing up when I run `fdisk -l` as root (ignore the errors; they're from all the GUID Partition Tables I have on my other drives):

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 64.0 GB, 64023257088 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7783 cylinders, total 125045424 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   125045423    62522711+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdd'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdd: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sde'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sde: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdf'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdf: 2000.4 GB, 2000397852160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907027055 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdf1               1  3907027054  1953513527   ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdg'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdg: 2000.4 GB, 2000397852160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907027055 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdg1               1  3907027054  1953513527   ee  GPT

Disk /dev/mapper/root: 26.8 GB, 26841448448 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3263 cylinders, total 52424704 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md127: 8001.6 GB, 8001580695552 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 1953510912 cylinders, total 15628087296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 2097152 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe8070000

Disk /dev/md127 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/home: 36.0 GB, 35967540736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4372 cylinders, total 70249103 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/home doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/data: 8001.6 GB, 8001578598400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 972803 cylinders, total 15628083200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 2097152 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/data doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

It doesn't show up as a device file in `/dev` either:

```
# ls /dev/sd*
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda3  /dev/sda4  /dev/sda5  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1  /dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1  /dev/sdd  /dev/sdd1  /dev/sde  /dev/sde1  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdf1  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdg1
```

These are all my regular hard drives, as you can see from the fdisk output above.

Answer (score 5):

This message is for recognised USB device. Normally you should also see messages about mass storage, notable about the drive capacity.

Try `modprobe usb-storage` to load driver for flash disks.

Comment: It was a kernel module problem. I'd just updated the kernel, so all it took was a reboot.